# Fill the background of list elements using CSS and jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have implemented a ruler using HTML and CSS. It currently looks like this:
[image]

When you click on an area of the ruler, it needs to highlight that specific are below the main horizontal line, like this:

[image]

However, right now I can't make it work. Instead of the highlighted area being below the main line, it is in the middle, like this:

[image]

Here is what I have done until now:

https://jsfiddle.net/km124/naqLsgt0/

```
$("ul.ruler li").mousedown(function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    return false;
  })
  .mouseover(function() {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
  });
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  isMouseDown = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's because you are setting background on the `<li>` tag. But you can't move it down because you need it's position for your `:after`.

So instead you can add a `:before` element and make it the same size like your `<li>` element and move it down a bit.

But first, you have to make your `<li>` elements `position: relative`

```css
.ruler li {
   /* ... your other styles */
   position: relative;
}
```

And the `:before` like so

```css
.highlighted:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: calc(100% + 2px); /* +2px height because of the horizontal ruler line */
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%; /* 50% because the horizontal line looks like it's at the middle of your <li> */
}
```

And here's your working example:

```js
let isMouseDown = false;

$("ul.ruler li").mousedown(function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    return false;
  })
  .mouseover(function() {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    }
  });
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  isMouseDown = false;
});
```

```css
.ruler {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   margin: 4em 2em;
   height: 2em;
   padding: 0;
   color: #ddd;
   outline: 2px currentColor solid;
   outline-offset: -2px;

   counter-reset: cm ;
   width: max-content;
   font: .85em Arial;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.ruler::before {
   display: block;
   width: max-content;
   content: "0";
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 100%;
   left: 2px;
   transform: translate(-50%, -1em)
}


.ruler li::after {
   content: counter(cm);
   counter-increment: cm;
   display: block;
   width: max-content;
   overflow: visible;
   color: #ddd;
   text-align: right;
   transform: translate(50%, -1.5em);
}

.ruler li:nth-child(2n - 1)::after {
   color: transparent;
}


.ruler li {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   color: transparent;
   width: 1cm;
   height: calc(2px + 1.5em);
   transform: translate(0, -.75em);
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-left: 2px #ddd solid;
   position: relative;
}

.ruler li:last-child {
   border-right: 2px #ddd solid;
}

.highlighted:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: red;
    height: calc(100% + 2px);
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ruler">
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>23</li>
    <li>24</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```